# Problem with show on hover button with mat-menu; active button disappears on click

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I've created a 'show on hover' mat-menu button as you can see here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-show-hide-menu?file=app%2Fshow-hide-menu.scss

The problem is, when I click the button it disappears, leaving me with an odd-looking mat-menu. I've tried targeting the button's active or focus states using css (shown in the example) but that doesn't appear to help keep the active button appear.

When you click the button in the example you will see the blue background flash when the button is active, however it doesn't stay blue. The blue background is there just to debug, but basically I want the 'display: flex' css to kick in whenever the button is clicked i.e. while the selected menu is active.

Any help greatly appreciated!

-S. Arora

Answer (score 3):

Your "More Options" button disappears because it's no longer active or focused after the menu opens. In fact, you can't make it active or focused because the menu creates a transparent backdrop layer that covers everything else on the screen, which you can see when you inspect the HTML. That's why you can't get the button to reappear while the menu is open.

One way around this is to watch the state of the menu itself and add a class to the button whenever its associated menu is open:

```
<button fxFlex="80" mat-icon-button matTooltip="More Options"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="optionsMenu" class="hover-display"
    #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [ngClass]="{ 'open': menuTrigger.menuOpen }">
```

Then you can use this class in your CSS instead of targeting the active or focused states:

```
.node .hover-display.open {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Wow..thanks!!! Make sense now why traditional css solutions I read didn't work in this case. I've posted the working version here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-show-hide-menu-testfix1?file=app%2Fshow-hide-menu.html